# pulling data from array into new independent variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[{…}]
0: {productName: "Powermax 125", travelSpeed: 30, materialThickness: 1, process: "125 Amps"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Hello, This is my console output from sorting 18 sets of information like this. I have successfully sorted the list to just the entry above. now I want to store each set of information into its own variable. This is in Javascript

The Variable above is `sortedList`

Can someone help me make code to pull each bit of information out as a new variable?

I tried

```
finalProduct = sortedList.productName
finalTravelSpeed = sortedlist.travelSpeed
finalMaterialThickness= sortedList.materialThickness
finalProcess = sortedlist.process
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what the question is here, it looks like you did it. What's the issue with the code above? Are you getting an error? Is it not doing what you expect?

Comment: Post the entire JSON so we can see where each key is.

Comment: yes, I am dynamically creating variables, I start with 18 sets of info, and am filtering to get just one set of info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood this is an array of objects of length 1, so first you should access index 0 of that array to get that object:

```
let finalProduct = sortedList[0].productName
let finalTravelSpeed = sortedlist[0].travelSpeed
let finalMaterialThickness= sortedList[0].materialThickness
let finalProcess = sortedlist[0].process
```

Answer (score 1):

You only make some little typos: you wrote in some cases `sortedlist` instead of `sortedList`, you didn't use camelCase-writing and you forgot the ";" and the line-end.
Because your sorted list is an array and you want the first element of it you allways have to take the first element `sortedList[0]` and not sortedList.

```js
let sortedList= [{productName: "Powermax 125", travelSpeed: 30, materialThickness: 1, process: "125 Amps"}];

finalProduct = sortedList[0].productName;
finalTravelSpeed = sortedList[0].travelSpeed;
finalMaterialThickness= sortedList[0].materialThickness;
finalProcess = sortedList[0].process;

console.log (finalProduct, finalTravelSpeed, finalMaterialThickness, finalProcess);
```

Comment: Judging by the way the JSON posted by the Jake starts, it looks like the keys are actually inside an array.

Comment: He might actually just need a loop to iterate through the array of info and do something like log it all out.

Comment: @Zachucks The OP gives us only an array with 1 element otherwise you are right to iterate through it.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood ! you want method to pulling

data from arrays or objects and put this data in dynamic variables have same name

```
var sortedList= [{productName: "Powermax 125", travelSpeed: 30, materialThickness: 1, process: "125 Amps"}];

// this function for extract objects to variables worked dynamically
function extractor_Object(obj = {}){
    for(let i in obj) window[i] = obj[i];
}

extractor_Object(sortedList[0]);


console.log(productName , travelSpeed , materialThickness , process);
```

i hope this function help you